# angularJS Do Not Display A Row Depending On Value In An NG-Grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am new to angularJS ad I have been asked to hide a row in my `ng-grid` table if a value of a column is '0'.

My `grid` has 4 columns:

- User
- Today
- This Week
- This Month

And I want to hide an entire row if 'This Month' column is '0'

My HTML for the `gird` is:

```
<div data-ng-controller="workflowworkitemscompleted as vm">
    <div data-ng-if="isbusy">
        <div data-cc-spinner="vm.spinnerOptions"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="gridStyle" style="height:157px" data-ng-grid="gridOptions" id="cwigrid"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My controller code is:

```
$scope.searchfilter = "";
    $scope.mySelections = [];
    $scope.sortInfo = { fields: ['countDay'], directions: ['desc'] };
    $scope.totalServerItems = 0;
    $scope.pagingOptions = {
        pageSizes: [5],
        pageSize: 5,
        currentPage: 1
    };

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'wfiprocessed',
        multiSelect: false,
        rowHeight: 25,
        showFooter: false,
        footerRowHeight: 40,
        enableColumnReordering: false,
        showColumnMenu: false,
        enableColumnResize: false,
        enableRowSelection: false,
        filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
        selectedItems: $scope.mySelections,
        enablePaging: false,
        pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
        plugins: [gridLayoutPlugin],
        totalServerItems: 'totalServerItems',
        sortInfo: $scope.sortInfo,
        useExternalSorting: false,
        virtualizationThreshold: 50,
        rowTemplate: "<div ng-style=\"{ 'cursor': row.cursor }\" ng-repeat=\"col in renderedColumns\" class=\"ngCell {{col.colIndex()}} {{col.cellClass}}\">" +
            "   <div class=\"ngVerticalBar\" ng-style=\"{height: rowHeight}\" ng-class=\"{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }\">&nbsp;</div>" +
            "   <div ng-cell></div>" +
            "</div>",
        columnDefs: [
            { field: 'userName', displayName: 'User', cellTemplate: vm.optimizedcell },
            { field: 'countDay', displayName: 'Today', cellTemplate: vm.optimizedcell },
            { field: 'countWeek', displayName: 'This Week', cellTemplate: vm.optimizedcell },
            { field: 'countMonth', displayName: 'This Month', cellTemplate: vm.optimizedcell }
        ]
    };
```

And my table looks like:
[image]

Looking at the table above, I don't want the 'dtealdev' or 'qauser2' rows to be displayed as the 'This Month' column is '0'

Comment: So preprocess the data you are getting from the data source and remove the columns that are returning `0`. then rebind the data source with the filtered object in the datasource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your data source of `$scope.gridOptions` you feed all the dataset you want to show in the grid. What you are doing is, you are passing the undesirable field i.e., `qauser2` and `dtealedev` in this data set too.

What you can do is return only the desired set of data values that need to show.

```
$scope.gridOptions.data = function(data) {
    //remove the items in data that contain 0 in all fields

    return newData;
}
```